# How do i get value of DataBinder.Eval in RowCommand without using cell index or DataKey

Tags: asp.net, gridview, databinder

I want the values without using cells as they might change later and the values i want are not primary key so i cant put them in datakeys so how can i get values in RowCommand event

I am getting Null value for this

```
strRequestMedium = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "RequestMedium"));
```

I tried to use row which was already getting me values from labels 
for ex:

```
   GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);

        strRequiredByDate = Convert.ToString(((Label)row.FindControl("lblRequiredDateTime")).Text);
```

But this was also not working as it is not allowed or something

Comment: Can you add some html and the actual method you're trying to do this in? The 2nd looks like an idea. What's the error or problem?

Comment: You can put multiple keys in `datakeys` and letter you can get these value. [Refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45366234/how-to-work-with-multiple-datakeys-in-gridview)

Comment: even if they are not primary keys ? @shekhar ?